# Verbatim in beamer showing error: "File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim."

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I am using Texmaker and MiKTeX on Windows 7. I have the following `beamer` code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\theme{AnnArbor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{verbatim}

   \begin{frame}[<alignment>]
   \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
   Frame body text and/or LATEX code
   \end{frame}

\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I was expecting the following output,

```
       \begin{frame}[<alignment>]
       \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
       Frame body text and/or LATEX code
       \end{frame}
```

But instead I got the following Error Message,

```
File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
```

Can any one please point out the error here. As far as I know verbatim can have anything inside it.

Also when I tried the following code,

```
\begin{verbatim}
 \ begin{frame}[<alignment>]
 \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
 Frame body text and/or LATEX code
 \ end{frame}
\end{verbatim}
```

I got the following output,

```
    \ begin{frame}[<alignment>]
     \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
     Frame body text and/or LATEX code
    \ end{frame}
```

But I don't want space between `\` and `begin` and `\` and `end`.

Comment: Related: [Why does `! Missing $ inserted.` occur when using \verb in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197234/5645)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your frame should be `fragile`. (One additional line commented for better effect).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\theme{AnnArbor}

\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{verbatim}

   \begin{frame}[<alignment>]
   \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
   Frame body text and/or LATEX code
   \end{frame}

\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: For me too, Fragile worked!!

Comment: This does not work for me. Even after marking the fram fragile, I cannot put `\end{verbatim}` on a newline after `\end{frame}` in this example or it gives the same error. I am forced to put `\end{verbatim}` on the same line, which then messes up syntax highlighting for the remainder of my file.

Answer (score 4):

Using `fragile` does not work for me when changing the mode as when generating slides and handouts from separate driver files calling the same content file so I came up with an ugly but effective work around. Let me give an example expanding on the one given above.

The driver file to create slides is called *contentfile.beamer* and has the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{contentfile}
```

A driver file for the handouts is called *contentfile.article* and has the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle, pgfpages}
\setjobnamebeamerversion{contentfile.beamer}
\input{contentfile}
```

The file named *contentfile* has the actual content of the slides and the comments:

```
\begin{document}

As seen in Figure~\ref{fig:slideWithVerbatim}
the small slide image appears on the article version only and
is ignored when compiled as a beamer document.
That is what makes it a handout.
By contrast this text is ignored when the document is
build with the beamer class.

\begin{figure}
\framebox{\includeslide[width=0.9\textwidth]{frameVerb}}
\label{fig:slideWithVerbatim}
\end{figure}

\mode<beamer>{
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \label{frameVerb} % this is the hook for the handout
  \begin{verbatim}

    \begin{frame}[<alignment>]
    \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
    Frame body text and/or LATEX code
    \end{frame}

  \end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

The workflow is to run pdfLaTeX on the *contentfile.beamer* first to generate the slides and then run it on *contentfile.article* to generate the handout.

This had worked wonderfully for me until trying to use verbatim inside a `frame` environment. The only work around so far has been:

1. Comment out the lines with `\mode<beamer>{` and the final `}` around the `frame` environment with the problematic verbatim text in the *contentfile* file.
2. Run pdfLaTeX on the *contentfile.beamer* file to generate the slides.
3. Uncomment the lines from step 1, this will enable the directive that isolates this code from the article mode.
4. Save the *contentfile* file and run pdfLaTeX on the *contentfile.article* file. This generates the handout version with the correct slides and avoids the collision with verbatim.

Awkward but it does work. I will be thankful to anyone sharing a more elegant and practical solution.

[image: Output generated with above code and work flow]

Answer (score 2):

I am posting it too late. But one easy solution is "Don't use frame at all".. Latex will automatically assign a frame.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}

   \begin{frame}[<alignment>]
   \frametitle{Frame Title Goes Here}
   Frame body text and/or LATEX code
   \end{frame}

\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

It will automatically assign a frame to the content and will not show any error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think that the point is that the OP was trying to show in a beamer talk how to use frames and so needed a frame displayed inside a frame, so your solution might compile but it doesn't help.