# \verb in \itemize?

Tags: beamer, itemize, verbatim

I want to make an itemized list with verbatim elements <del>which contain underscores</del> (*actually `\verb` just doesn't work*) . So far, nothing I have tried worked. Escaping doesn't work, and I have tried `examples` but that package is broken. How can I achieve what I want ?

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Sorting algorithms}
\begin{frame}{Sorting algorithms}
    Three algorithms :
    \begin {itemize}
        \item \verb"bubble_sort"
        \item \verb"strand_sort"
        \item \verb"pigeonhole_sort"
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `frame` containing verbatim material must be set with the `fragile` option (so `\begin{frame}[fragile]`). Preferable would be to use `\item\texttt{bubble\_sort}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Great ! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it ? It would be nice if other people can find this instead of the other questions I found which give broken answers !

Comment: (1) It is recommended to use `\begin{frame}\frametitle{title}`, (2) as Skillmon mentions use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` when using special constructions like `\verb` etc. Then your example compiles just fine

Comment: @Skillmon If not I'll do it but you deserve the reputation not me

Comment: @Crysambrosia In essence this is a duplicate (I was just too lazy to search). See e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197234 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140719